Code Syntax Highlighting - Is Code In-Scope For Bitcoin.SE?
Stéphane Gimenez asked this question earlier today and it would make sense to me if the code syntax highlighting option were enabled for Bitcoin.SE. Granted we're nowhere near SO levels of code-sharing, but we do have development, programming, source and code tags and a fair amount of code-sharing does occur (mostly PHP and Python but some other stuff) for which syntax highlighting would be quite helpful.
The real question is one of scope: if a question is sufficiently about coding that syntax highlighting would be that helpful should it have been asked on SO instead or are we willing to discuss things like the Bitcoin (and related projects') source code here? If the latter, we should probably get this feature enabled. What does the community think?

Should this question be retitled as "Code Syntax and SE Site Scope" or similar?

The site-crossover tag is commonly used on SO, so I've added it here.

@HighlyIrregular: good point, my title wasn't really phrased as a question. Fixed.

I think it would make more sense to include it in the Bitcoin site when the question about the code is Bitcoin (or cryptocurrency) specific. 
There may be cases where a question turns out to be more of a general coding issue, in which case SO is probably more appropriate.
The scope question will also be relevant for the SuperUser and ServerFault sites. Those users who are familiar with the other sites should have a feel as to where each question is more appropriate. For example, this question on ServerFault is much more appropriate there than in the Bitcoin site.
